# Cesium label blurred

Tags: cesiumjs

I created a Cesium label, using the following code:

```
        var label: Cesium.LabelGraphics = new Cesium.LabelGraphics({
            text : lab,
            verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
            horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
            font: '15px Helvetica',
            fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
            outlineWidth: 2,
            style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
            pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(20, 20)
        });
```

But it is blurred...

I would like to have a clearer label. Is this image you can see inside the red rectangle the real label. In the blue rectangle is the label with a zoom In. In the green rectangle is how I would like it to be.
[image]

Is there some way to make the label clearer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Bllboard.js or Cesium.js  change

```
gl_Position = czm_viewportOrthographic * vec4(positionWC.xy,-positionWC.z, 1.0);
```

to

```
gl_Position = czm_viewportOrthographic * vec4(floor(positionWC.xy + 0.5), -positionWC.z, 1.0);
```

It will makethe billboards snap to a pixel, instead of get blurred.

also disable the FXAA (antialias) in your viewer initialization

```
viewer.scene.fxaa = false
```

it will make the billboards and labels much more crispy !

Before

[image: before]
.

After

[image: after]

Comment: The Cesium team did some experimenting with this answer.  It turns out, the shader code change shown above is not effective here at all.  The real "active ingredient" in this solution is setting `viewer.scene.fxaa = false;`.  That's currently the only means to fix the blurring.  So our official recommendation is, set fxaa to false and don't take the shader code change.

Comment: We'll continue to track this issue as a bug in Cesium: https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/4235

Comment: @emackey the shader modification only allows the the images be rendered at 1x1 pixel. It's not a good practice when the billboard is scaled. However if the scale is made 1x1 it's renders pixel by pixel from billboard data to viewport.

Comment: Have you tried it with fxaa enabled?  Because we tried that yesterday, it's not as simple as you describe.  The fxaa thwarts it.  Read the issue I linked to.

Answer (score 5):

A trick I sometimes use is to combine a larger font size with a `scale` setting on the label to scale the large font down using WebGL.  This is a slightly different scaling than simply picking a smaller font size, because WebGL's texture scaling system comes into play to scale the rasterized font images.  This works because Cesium labels are not anchored to an integer pixel position, they can be placed at coordinates with sub-pixel precision.  So, the extra resolution in the label texture comes in handy as the label moves around.  Of course this method costs a little bit more texture memory, but is usually worth it to get the cleaner edges.

Here's an example, showing the difference between normal (no scaling), double (0.5 scaling), and triple (roughly, 0.3 scaling).

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationHelpButton: false, animation: false, timeline: false
});

viewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
    label : {
        text : 'Label == || normal',
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
        horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
        font: '15px Helvetica',        // NOTE: Standard size, no scaling here.
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineWidth: 2,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(20, -10)
    }
});

viewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
    label : {
        text : 'Label == || double',
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
        horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
        font: '31px Helvetica',
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineWidth: 2,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(20, 20),
        scale: 0.5
    }
});

viewer.entities.add({
    position : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-75.1641667, 39.9522222),
    label : {
        text : 'Label == || triple',
        verticalOrigin: Cesium.VerticalOrigin.TOP,
        horizontalOrigin: Cesium.HorizontalOrigin.RIGHT,
        font: '57px Helvetica',        // NOTE: Large font size here
        fillColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
        outlineWidth: 2,
        style: Cesium.LabelStyle.FILL,
        pixelOffset: new Cesium.Cartesian2(20, 50),
        scale: 0.3       // NOTE: Large font images scaled down via WebGL texturing.
    }
});
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: That helps for sure, but is there something like a "snap to pixel" functionality?

Comment: Not in Cesium currently.  I think there is a way to get the screen position, so you could put an HTML DOM element on top of the canvas at that location.  It wouldn't take part in depth-testing, but gives the clarity of DOM text if you really need it.